# Set TBLProperties using Scala API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I am writing data into a table with mode `overwrite`

And since I have special characters in my columnname I need to set below three properties for the column mapping.

- `'delta.minReaderVersion' = '2',`
- `'delta.minWriterVersion' = '5',`
- `'delta.columnMapping.mode' = 'name'`

So would like to know is there a way to set TBLProperties using Scala API ?

I tried this but not working

```
myDf.write.mode("Overwrite")
.option("delta.minReaderVersion", "2")
.option("delta.minWriterVersion", "5")
.option("delta.columnMapping.mode", "name")
.saveAsTable("testDB.employees")
```

Comment: Does this help ? https://docs.databricks.com/delta/versioning.html#0-language-scala But reading between the lines, does not seem to be recommended to be changed manually...

Answer (score 1):

Not test with `databricks` but try this may help:

```scala
df.write.format("delta")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .option("TBLPROPERTIES", "key1=value1, key2=value2")
  .save("/path/to/table")
```

Comment: This does not appear to work on Databricks 13.3 LTS. Trying to write the table still yields an error about invalid characters in column names.